# What prior would lead to $\ell_\infty$ regularization of model weights?

Tags: probability, distributions, generalized-linear-model, regularization, prior

- Gaussian prior on weights of a GLM lead to Ridge / $\ell_2$ squared regularization.
- Laplace prior leads to $\ell_1$ regularization

## Question

What prior would lead to $\ell_\infty$ regularization ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking of similar examples, the reason behind the correspondence between these priors and norms is the exponent part. 
$$f(\beta)\propto \exp(-\lambda||\beta||_1)\rightarrow \ell_1$$
$$f(\beta)\propto \exp(-\lambda||\beta||^2_2)\rightarrow \ell_2 \text{  squared}$$
So, if we have a prior in the form below, it will correspond to $\ell_\infty$ because the negative log likelihood will directly include the term $\lambda||\beta||_{\infty}$ as a summand.
$$f(\beta)\propto \exp(-\lambda||\beta||_\infty)\rightarrow \ell_\infty$$

I don't know if this PDF has a name, but it is a proper one ($n$ is the dimension):
$$f(\beta)=\frac{\lambda^n}{2^nn!}\exp(-\lambda||\beta||_\infty)$$

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.